# Bash script works in Terminal but in Applescript gives "python3: command not found"

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, applescript

**SOLVED: see solution in replies**

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /Users/me/path/to/my/file.py
python3 /Users/me/path/to/my/file2.py
Rscript /Users/me/path/to/my/rfile.R
python3 /Users/me/path/to/my/file.py
```

When I execute it from terminal with the command

`bash /Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh`

it executes perfectly. However, I would like to be able to run it from Keyboard Maestro or AppleScript. In AppleScript, when I run

`do shell script "bash /Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh"`

I get the following error message:

```
error "/Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh: line 2: python3: command not found
/Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh: line 3: python3: command not found
/Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh: line 4: Rscript: command not found
/Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh: line 5: python3: command not found" number 127
```

I receive the same error message if I run the equivalent command in Keyboard Maestro. I have tried changing `python3` to `python`, but it fails anyway because it runs the files in Python 2 (despite the shebang of the Python files specifying Python 3), and the `Rscript` command would surely still throw an error.

What is the difference between the environments that causes the shell script to fail in Keyboard Maestro and AppleScript but not Terminal?

Comment: `do shell script` uses a default shell, so it doesn't have _any_ of your environment settings.

Comment: @red_menace How would I fix this?

Comment: The easiest would be to not use anything specific to your environment, for example use full paths.

Comment: @red_menace I am already using full paths for every reference in every program. The programs never get run, though; the shell script stops because the `python3` command is not recognized.
EDIT: I solved it, answer in reply

Comment: You would have had to use the full path of the executables as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing the command to `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; bash /Users/me/path/to/my/shellscript.sh`.

Comment: So basically, it's exactly what @red_menace advised, which was to use full paths. You don't need to set the `PATH` variable; you just need to use **full paths**, i.e. **`do shell script`**_`"/bin/bash ~/path/to/my/shellscript.sh"`_ (or _`/usr/local/bin/bash`_ if you prefer). You could also have opted to make `shellscript.sh` executable, which would negate the need to call `bash` explicitly.